# Multi variable update with if else shorthand

Tags: javascript

I want to update multiple values with if else shorthand, like this:

```
let a = 0;
let b = 1;
let bool = true;

if(bool) {
  a = 4;
  b = 7;
}
```

with shorthand like this:

```
bool ? a = 8, b = 10 : null
```

but `Unexpected token ,`

Comment: Put the expression between parenthesis.

Comment: If it has to be on one line (why, do you have a shortage of lines?), why not `if (bool) { a = 8; b = 10; }`? There's basically no reason to make it an expression with a superfluous `null`.

Comment: its not about one line, its about shorthand

Comment: The `?:` solution is one character more than `if ...`, the `&&` solution is 4 characters less. Not sure what you're really saving here, and it's more obscure than an explicit `if`.

Comment: But in my application Im just wrote 9 line with shorthand, instead of 16 line vs. not shorthand.

Comment: Which one is more readable and maintainable? Again, if the goal is to use as few lines as possible, there are [more extreme measures](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) you could take…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a logical AND.

```
bool && (a = 8, b = 10);
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) says:

> You can use the comma operator when you want to include multiple expressions in a location that requires a single expression.

Comment: I really like this solution, but Suren was the first :)

Comment: @peter, not really, it was just in the grace period.

Comment: @peter Accept Nina's answer. I have updated my answer after she provided her

Comment: @SurenSrapyan Gentle Man  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap them in the `()`. It will evaluate expressions inside `()` and return the last one's result.

```
bool ? (a = 8, b = 10) : null
```

But if you consider `null` and `undefined` to be the same you can just use `&&`

```
bool && (a = 8, b = 10)
```